# Access to properties of JSON in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to access the age but I cannot, how can I do that?

```
var json = '{"carlos":{"data":{"age":"30","phone":"3226458186"}}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
```

This doesn't work for me, `obj.carlos` is `undefined`

```
console.log("Age of Carlos: ", obj.carlos.data.age);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the unnecessary call to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), that method is used to convert JavaScript objects to JSON, but has nothing to do with deserializing them.

The code that you need is just this:

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to `JSON.stringify`. You just only need to parse your values as they are already a `JSON` string. Here you go:

```js
var json = '{"carlos":{"data":{"age":"30","phone":"3226458186"}}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log("Age: ", obj.carlos.data.age);
```

Comment: The answer should also inform the asker what was wrong with their attempt at solving the problem and contain explanation why the changes that were made were made.

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is the unnecessary call to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))` conver javascript object to JSON like: `JSON.parse(json)`

```
example : 

 var json = '{"carlos":{"data":{"age":"30","phone":"3226458186"}}}';
 var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
 console.log("Phone of Carlos: ", obj.carlos.data.phone);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use JSON.stringify() here, because this method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string and you already got a JSON string.
So your code should look like this:

```
var json = '{"carlos":{"data":{"age":"30","phone":"3226458186"}}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: _"this method converts a JavaScript object to a JSON string"_ Well, not necessarily an Object. You can stringify a String, a Number, a Boolean, `null`, a non-circular Array, a non-circular Object... It's just not what the OP wants in this particular case. For example, `JSON.stringify('foo')` will output `'"foo"'` with double quotes embedded into the String to make it valid JSON